Visma.net ERP Service WebHooks are not working
I'm using Visma.net erp Service API Integration web hooks,  I've created a web hook , Visma Connect IdP with Event Tenant Application Added.
I'm connecting through free version of ngrok to forward url to local host url for testing.
When test ngrok url into postman directly , its working, but it is not working, in case when new company connected with visma app on app store. then Webhook event does not occur and Asp.Net core local server does not accept any request. Even both are active.
Can any one resolve the issue, thanks
